# How to change URL in address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .htaccess

I have static html files and I want to be able to **remove** the `.html` file extension at the end of the url inside the address bar.

So instead of `/contact-us.html` - I want it to display as this `/?contact-us`

One thing to notice here is there is a question mark before the page name(s). I want to do this to any html page not just `contact-us.html`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look for "url rewriting".

Comment: It's really up to the HTTP server, I'm guessing it's apache? Javascript can push a fake entry into the history, making it look like you are actually at `/?contact-us` but not really.

Comment: Does your URL actually look like `http://domain.com/?contact-us.html` if So what is the reason for the query string in the URL? It will matter when making the rules.

Comment: no the url string looks like this `http://domain.com/contact-us.html` i just want the url to look cleaner without the `.html` and add a question mark before the file name @PanamaJack

Comment: possible through `.htaccess` or jquery? @PanamaJack

Comment: My question is why do you need a query string? It's point less if it's just for looks. The rule is pretty simple otherwise

Comment: i don't need it - i just wanted to know if it was possible to add the question mark before the page @PanamaJack

Comment: It would overly complicate your URL. Rewrites are usually to remove query string type URLs and write them to folder like /contact-us. I can show that.

Comment: I think what I need to do is use ajax to call separate file names and then change the URL that way.. i need to experiment a little more. @PanamaJack thanks though

Comment: to do what your asking does not require any ajax or javascript. You do it will rewrites

Answer (score 1):

You can rewite the single page in your .htaccess using this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule    ^/contact-us.html$    /?contact-us    [NC,L]
```

More specifically, if you want to rewrite all .html extensions you can use a regular expression to match a pattern of pages:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)(.html)$    /?$1    [NC,L]
```

In the above example, it will match any .html extension.  e.g. /example-page.html will be /?example-page

You can test it out at an htaccess tester here: http://htaccess.mwl.be/

*However*, question mark (?) is reserved for query strings, and your rewrites may end up in an infinite loop because the rule will rewrite http://www.example.com/example-page.html to http://www.example.com/?example-page, which the server will resolve to http://www.example.com/index.html?example-page, which in turn triggers another re-write, ad infinitum.

A better approach would be to mock a directory structure, and re-write /example-page.html to /example-page/  This gives you some SEO benefits as well, and can be done with this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)(.html)$    /?$1/    [NC,L]
```

Comment: what if we want it for all the pages. not just `contact-us.html` @Adam Konieska

Comment: You'll need to write a regular expression to target the patterns you want, and the pattern to replace with.  Try looking up some regex and htaccess tutorials.

Comment: I also updated the answer with an example that would rewrite *all* .html extensions to match your output.

Comment: it isn't working for me. not sure what i am doing wrong. I'm putting these lines inside the `.htaccess` file but nothing, it gives me a server error. @Adam Konieska

Comment: Its possible you are entering a redirect loop.  Your server likely has a default file (or files) it looks for when a directory is requested.  e.g. accessing the root directory http://www.example.com/ will retrieve the page http://www.example.com/index.html

The question mark is reserved for url query strings, and its likely your rewrite rule is resulting in an infinite loop trying to resolve the default page (index.html)
I'd strongly recommend *not* rewriting to things like /example-page.html to /?example-page for this reason.  Instead, you might try /example-page.html to /example-page/

Comment: yeah i figured that was causing the issue. hmm thanks for your time and answer on this. i was trying to figure it out how to make it look more like an app than html files - by adding the `?` before the file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use folder path instead of .html you need these rules.

This allows you to use `http://domain.com/contact-us` in the address bar.

```
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /+(.+)\.html [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L] 

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```